# Getting httpResponseMessage when trying to add Certificate to function app

Tags: azure, azure-functions, certificate, azure-keyvault

I am deploying a function app via ARM template. I have added the following snippet to add the certificate from the Azure Key vault and the added a host name binding.

```
{
              "type": "Microsoft.Web/certificates",
              "apiVersion": "2019-08-01",
              "name": "[parameters('certificateName')]",
              "location": "North Europe",
              "dependsOn": [
                  "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('functionAppName'))]"
              ],
              "properties": {
                  "keyVaultId": "[resourceId(parameters('keyvaultRG'), 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults', parameters('keyvaultName'))]",
                  "keyVaultSecretName": "[parameters('existingKeyVaultSecretName')]",
                  "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverFarms', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]"
              }
          },
          {
              "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/hostnameBindings",
              "name": "[concat(parameters('functionAppName'), '/', parameters('customDomainName'))]",
              "apiVersion": "2019-08-01",
              "location": "North Europe",
              "dependsOn": [
                  "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/certificates', parameters('certificateName'))]"
              ],
              "properties": {
                  "sslState": "SniEnabled",
                  "thumbprint": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/certificates', parameters('certificateName'))).Thumbprint]"
              }
          }
```

But when I don deploy the ARM template I get the following error at Microsoft.Web/certificates
"message": "The parameter httpResponseMessage has an invalid value."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please check if the below steps help to fix the issue**:

> error at Microsoft.Web/certificates "message": "The parameter {0} has an invalid value."

**Follow the below steps to fix this issue**:

- Enable the `Microsoft.Web` resource provider to direct access the Azure Key Vault using the Azure PowerShell.

```
Login-AzureRmAccount 
Set-AzureRmContext -SubscriptionId AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID 
Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName KEY_VAULT_NAME -ServicePrincipalName <ServicePrincipalId> -PermissionsToSecrets get
```

- Check the Access Policies of Azure Key Vault: Azure Key Vault > Access Policies > Add New (`Microsft.Web`) `Your-Function-App`
- Azure PowerShell Commands for inserting the certificate to the KeyVault:

```
$pfxFilePath = "PFX_CERTIFICATE_FILE_PATH" # Change this path 
$pwd = "PFX_CERTIFICATE_PASSWORD" # Change this password 
$flag = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]::Exportable 
$collection = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2Collection 
$collection.Import($pfxFilePath, $pwd, $flag) 
$pkcs12ContentType = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ContentType]::Pkcs12 
$clearBytes = $collection.Export($pkcs12ContentType) 
$fileContentEncoded = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($clearBytes) 
$secret = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $fileContentEncoded -AsPlainText –Force 
$secretContentType = 'application/x-pkcs12' 
Set-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName KEY_VAULT_NAME -Name KEY_VAULT_SECRET_NAME -SecretValue $Secret -ContentType $secretContentType # Change Name of Azure KV & Secret
```

Next step is using the `KeyVaultSecretName` for directly accessing the KeyVault in order to get the value.

**`WebSite.parameters`**:

```
 {
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-08-01/deploymentParameters.json",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "functionAppName": {
      "value": "yourfunctionappname"
    },
    "customHostname": {
      "value": "yourcustomdomianname"
    },
    "existingKeyVaultId": {
      "value": "/subscriptions/subscriptionsID/resourceGroups/resourceGroupsName/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/vaultsName"
    },
    "existingKeyVaultSecretName": {
      "value": "The key vaults SecretName"
    }
  }
}
```